# Convertir Textbox a array

Tags: c#

, como puedo hacer para convertir los datos de un texto tipo string ejem "43367874" a un array de tipo int ejem `array[0] = 4`,`array[1] = 3`,`array[2] = 3`...

estoy trabajando con Windows Formas Framework.net c#

Comment: Puedes usar `int[] ints = tuString.Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray();`

Comment: Si no quieres usar Linq, y que se realice la conversión solo si es un número, usa un for convirtiendo mediante `int.TryParse`.